# a5paper setting not taking effect

Tags: paper-size, article

I would like to set the page size to the European A5. I wrote the following:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
...
```

And process it with:

```
xelatex main.tex
```

The PDF that comes out doesn't look right. The actual printed area appears to be A5 but the size of the physical page is the US letter page.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64996/1340.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

In this way the package will not make any modification to the standard settings, and will only tell the compiler the physical page size.

For nonstandard paper size, usage of `geometry` (without the `pass` option) is the best choice anyway.

Comment: Do these settings `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` produce the same effect as your answer does?

Comment: @xport: no; **geometry** applies its own settings.

Comment: @egreg: Without using geometry package, we can use `\special{papersize=...,...}` right?

Comment: @xport: the `\special` trick works with "(la)tex+dvips" or "xe(la)tex", but not with "pdf(la)tex" or "lua(la)tex".

Comment: Without knowing the dimensions, you can set `\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65032/1340). Setting the PDF dimensions to different values won't work well - not without updating LaTeX margins and the rest of the layout.

Comment: @cabohah I just removed that part. If one wants nonstandard paper size, using `geometry` is needed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `xelatex`, you can use `\special{papersize=<width>,<height>}` instead of using `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` as follows.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\special{papersize=148mm,210mm}% it is A5 paper size, I got from Wikipedia.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Hi, I am xport !
\end{document}
```