# A5 paper with customised margins

Tags: luatex, geometry, article

I would like to create a leaflet in DIN A5 with customised page margins using article. However using `a5paper` as an argument of the documentclass does not have any effect on the output (still being DIN A4) but customised margins to be applied. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22917/a5paper-setting-not-taking-effect) question suggests the `pass` argument for `geometry`, however then any attempt to change the marins is ignored. The MWE is compiled with LuaLaTeX and overleaf but the results are consistent on local installations.

I have tried any combination of `pass`, `a5paper` and `\special{papersize=148mm,210mm}` (also as an argument of geometry) but never got A5 paper and custom margins.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, fontsize=9.5pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, top=5mm, pass]{geometry}
\special{papersize=148mm,210mm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\usepackage[showframe, top=5mm, paper=a5paper, twoside]{geometry}` and note that there's no `fontsize=9.5pt` class option for `article`.

Comment: Just to explain it: Option `pass` makes all other options (except information options like `verbose` and `showframe`) ineffective. But in opposite to the linked question you *want* to change the margins and therefore need effective options. So you should not use this option. See the `geometry` manual for more information.

Comment: But when not using `pass` I do not get an A5 paper but the default A4.